# How can I attach a Command with parameter to a *new* ContextMenu item?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I've attached commands to each of my context menu items as mentioned in other threads:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/LabelledFieldStyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="ContextMenuItemStyle">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type PetRegistry:RegistrationPanel}},Path=DataContext.CopyCommand}" />
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</StackPanel.Resources>
<Label Name="copyPetContextTarget" 
       Content="(Right-click here to copy an existing pet's details)" Width="Auto">
    <Label.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="copyPetMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Pets}"
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContextMenuItemStyle}"
                    Visibility="Visible">
            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Label.ContextMenu>
</Label>
```

The `ItemsSource` is connected to `Pets`, which is an `ObservableCollection`. When I add a new pet, "Fluffy", it shows up in the list of context menu items. However, there's no command attached - selecting merely closes the menu without triggering the command.

Strangely, using a list instead of an ObservableCollection and notifying the relevant property change doesn't even cause the new pet to show up in the menu.

How can I make a new pet bind to the command when it's added? Or is this just a strange bug?

Edit: It's working fine for existing pets. The binding isn't necessarily the problem - it's only not attaching when a new pet is added to the list. I'm sure code-behind will work - I'm thinking that maybe there's some property I need to notify about, or some way of binding the command differently. Otherwise I'm just going to write some code-behind.

Edit2: Interesting! There's actually an error being output (silently as is the way with WPF) - it can't find the binding. Is there a different way of getting hold of that parent data context which might be simpler?

Edit3: @Yurec nailed it, but while this works manually, it *fails* for Microsoft UI Automation. Doh! So I've created a `CopiablePet` object which has the CopyCommand embedded in it. Ugly, but it works. Will file a bug report with Microsoft if I get round to it as this is very silly.

Comment: I think your mistake is that you think that `ItemContainerStyle` is a `ButtonBase` class, but it is not. It doesn't have Command property.

Comment: The Command is working fine for the pets which are already there. It's only the new one which isn't binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reason for such behaviour is because menu items are not in the same visual tree as PetRegistry:RegistrationPanel. Please try to replace Command binding to something  like this

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}},Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.CopyCommand}" />
```

Of course Label should contain the same DataContext as PetRegistry:RegistrationPanel.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks, Yurec. This was exactly what I needed. Big kudos to @Tigran for patient discussion and helping work out that it was the Ancestor finding that was the problem.

Comment: Oh, the label automatically picks up its parent's data context too. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

I used in one of mine project something like this and it works for me:

```
<Style x:Key="FrameSubmenuItem" TargetType="MenuItem">
.....
....
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="NavigationCommands.NavigateJournal"/>
    <Setter Property="CommandTarget"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}},
                            Path=TemplatedParent}"/>
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
.....

...
```

Look on `CommandTarget` use.

**EDIT**

**Check the command binding by applying a Converter, at least for test reason, cause most likely, the binding of the command for new menu items somehow fails.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a routed command. Does this work if a new menu item is added to the collection too? If so, I might look at changing the way it works... but I still can't see why my way doesn't.

Comment: hmm.. no actually mine is a static menuitem.. but what happens if you assign a command from code behind? does it work in that way at least?

Comment: I'm sure it *would*, but I'd rather find out if there's a WPF way of doing it first. If there isn't, it strikes me as something of a bug. There's already a lot of oddities around ContextMenu.

Comment: @Lunivore IF this is not too big list of items, may be you can statitcaly link all of them, and after hide/show them based on app state..

Comment: it's a changing list of items and it might theoretically get quite large.

Comment: @Lunivore did you tried to define in style some other property, let's say Background, and see if that property actually applied to a NEW menu item? I mean, to identify if this is in general Style assigment or Style's content assignment problem.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. All menu items are now red, including the new one (defined in the style at the top). So the Style is being assigned, but the command is not.

Comment: @Lunivore: so it can be something related to visual tree construction during dynamic menuitems generation, and probably FindAncestor fails somehow...

Comment: Looks like exactly that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hm, that would make sense... except that the original pets already in the menu are binding with no problem at all. The error I'm seeing indicates that the command binding is failing, probably because of FindAncestor, *when the new pet is added* - not when I use the menu.

Comment: @Tigran let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2769/discussion-between-lunivore-and-tigran)